# Visibility of a button in an input submit button contained in a form

Tags: php, html

I have a form that contains an input submit button. If in the HTML, I explicitly set the button's visibility to visible by using `style="visibility: visible"` inside the input tag, then in the PHP when I hide the form, the form is hidden but the button remains visible.

However, if I do not set the button's visibility in the form, the button is visible, but it hides along with the form when I hide the form in PHP.

I am quite confused because I read the default setting of a button in a form in HTML is visible, so why does the button not hide with the form when I hide the form if I set its visibility to true?

Comment: Please provide code for better understanding..

Comment: An elements inline style has higher priority than CSS rules, which is a reason you sometimes get unexpected behaviors when using them. It's better to define it in CSS classes, which you can add/remove on an element. That's one of the reasons it's not recommended to use inline styles. My question is why you manually set it to `visible` in the first place if it works as expected without?

Comment: Other than `display:none`, `visibility:hidden` can simply be overwritten for descendant elements. _“I read the default setting of a button in a form in html is visible”_ - an implied default is something else than an explicitly set value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided no code all I can give you is the CSS specificity rules from MDN. Your issue is related to your inline style taking priority:

"The following list of selector types increases by specificity:

```
Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., ::before).
Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
ID selectors (e.g., #example).
```

Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ') and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity. (The selectors declared inside :not() do, however.)

Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity."